# Can I COUNTIFS where a cell is NOT less than or equal to a date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I want to count a range where one of my criterion is NOT less than or equal to a date in another cell. But blanks are okay, so I can't just say the criterion is greater than that date in the other cell. Meaning that I want to count the cells that are either blank or after the given date. I've tried the following criterion but get a parse error because of the last, **bolded criterion**:

=countifs(Sheet2!$B:$B,"Example",Sheet2!$E:$E,**<>"<="&B2**)

B2=3/31/2017

Sheet2!E:E are cells either with dates entered or left blank

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Add two COUNTIFS together, one with the criterion as greater than and the other with the criterion as blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one more for good measure:

```
=countif(Sheet2!$B:$B,"Example") - countifs(Sheet2!$B:$B,"Example",Sheet2!$E:$E,"<="&B2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, add the blanks to those that meet your criteria:

For example:

```
=COUNTBLANK(theRange)+COUNTIF(theRange,">"&A2)
```

where `theRange` refers to, for example `B2:B10`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

complementing @BigBen's response.

Try this:

```
=countifs(Sheet2!$B:$B,"Example",Sheet2!$E:$E,">="&B2)+countifs(Sheet2!$B:$B,"Example",Sheet2!$E:$E,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

*I want to count the cells that are either blank or after the given date*

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$16>E2)+--($A$1:$A$16=""))
```

[image]

This is how it works:

1. `--($A$1:$A$16>E2` will return an array of 1 and 0, depending if cell value is **greater* than value in E2. In this case we'll get `{0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1}`
2. `--($A$1:$A$16="")` will return an array of 1 and 0, depending if cell is blank or not. In this case we'll get `{0;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`
3. `+`will sum up both arrays, so we get `{0;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1}`
4. `SUMPRODUCT` will sum up that array into a single number, in this case, 10.

Other cases:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: just a note.  If you are going to add or multiply two or more booleans together the `--` are not needed.  the `--` is only needed if the boolean stands alone.  it is akin to `-1*-1*...`  By adding or multiplying other booleans or anything for that matter the same effect is done to the Boolean.

Comment: @ScottCraner you mean I could do `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$16>E2)+($A$1:$A$16=""))` like this?

Comment: yes, as long as you do some mathematical operation on the Boolean it will convert to the 1/0.